# Transfer logic/expression to the controller inside nested for loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have here a running/working code and i'm struggling to optimize it.

**Code below:**

```
@foreach($semesters as $semester)
    @foreach($student->subjects->where('semester_id', $semester->id) as $subject)
       {{ $subject->name }}
       //some code here
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

So basically, i want to transfer this `$student->subjects->where('semester_id', $semester->id`expression to the controller however, the query is dependent on the 'semester' loop. How do you optimize or refactor the code?

**Note: I need to get the *subject* model from the *student* since they are related with pivot and i need that relationship for this case.**

Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit**

Eloquent Model Relationships:

**Subject Model:**

```
public function teacher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
}

public function semester()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Semester::class);
}

public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)
        ->withPivot('accepted')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Student Model:**

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class)
        ->wherePivot('accepted', '=',1)
        ->withPivot('accepted')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Semester Model:**

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
}
```

**Teacher Model:**

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Student $student)) {
     $student->subjects->load('teacher');
     $semesters = Semester::whereIn('id', $student->subjects->pluck('semester_id'))->get();
     return view(....);
}
```

Comment: what about the relationship between ```semesters``` and ```student``` ? can you give the related controller and model? It will help to give the answer.

Comment: Eloquent Model Relationships:

Semester has many subjects Subject belongs to semester

Comment: what about student, subject and teacher?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the models.

Comment: what is your expecting output?

Comment: expected output: 
1st semester
    $subject->name  +   $subject->teacher->name
then loop around all semester

Comment: All i'm asking is how to remove the where query inside the loop. i can't seem to solve it using eager loading.

Comment: Using below code you can get all semester output.
```@foreach($student->subjects->load('teacher')->get() as $subject)
       {{ $subject->name }}
       {{ $subject->teacher->name }}
@endforeach```

Comment: what about above code?

Comment: i don't understand how does that work. the code given in the question was working and the 'where' query and semester loop is necessary. actually. you can forget about the load('teacher') . it can be done in the controller.

Comment: I edited the question and made it simpler.

Comment: what about your controller?

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this in your controller

```php
use App\Semester;
use App\Student;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewManager;

public function yourMethod(ViewManager $viewManager)
{
    $semesters = Semester::all();
    $student = App\Student::with(['subjects' => function ($query) use ($semesters) {
        $query->whereIn('semester_id', $semesters->pluck('id'));
    }])->firstOrFail();

    return $viewManager->make('yourView', compact('semesters', 'student'));
}
```

```php
@foreach ($semesters as $semester)
    @foreach ($semester->subjects as $subject)
        {{ $subject->name }}
        //Your code
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I need to get the 'subjects' from the 'student' since they are related with Pivot. (see above question and the models and the controller).  that's is why i was forced to use the 'where' query for semester.

Comment: it's practically the same with your previous answer. the idea is to load this relationship "$student->subjects" since i need this 'wherePivot('accepted', '=',1)' query in the 'student' model.

Answer (score 0):

You will change your controller like

```
$student->subjects->load('teacher');
$semesters = Semester::whereIn('semeters.id', $student->subjects->pluck('semester_id'))
->join('subjects', 'semesters.subject_id', 'subjects.id')
->whereIn('subjects.id', $student->pluck('subject_id'))
->select('semesters.id as id', 'subjects.name as subject_name', ....) //what every values you want
->get();
return view(....);
```

and change your blade like

```
@foreach ($semesters as $semester)
      {{ $semester->id }}
      {{ $semester->subject_name }}
        //Your code
@endforeach
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: I would just like to clarify that i need to get 'subjects' from the 'students' not from the 'semester' since they are related with pivot. see models.

Comment: The solution became complicated than the question. I probably will stick with the original code since it is more readable and have lesser queries. Thank you anyway.